# Difference between a JSF and a Maven project

Tags: maven, jsf, intellij-idea, setup-project

For my new JAVA application, I want to start creating a new JSF2.2 project with IntelliJ. This project will be a web application and will be using maven.

In IntelliJ Idea, when i click on "create a new project", and then in the left panel select "Maven", it gives me the option of "create from archetype". If I select this check box, it gives me a list of archetypes, with many including jsf in their names.

I am confused what is the difference in creating a maven project without these archetypes and giving it my own groupId, artifactid and so on as compared to creating a project with any of the given jsf archetype?

Like I stated above, the project that i am starting will be a JSF based web application.

**EDIT 1**
I made the project with maven-archtype-webapp and it created a file index.jsp in the webapp folder. Is this a problem as i normally work with .xhtml files

Answer (score 0):

Maven archetypes are templates. They create a proper project structure for you, depending on whether you want to create a standalone, JSF, ear etc. project.

All these projects are built with Maven, and create a GAV (groupId:artifactId:version) for the created artifacts.